# Saving list of pandas dataframes for use in another file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, save

I have written an optimization algorithm that tests some functions on historical stock data, then returns a 2d list of the pandas dataframes generated by each run and the function parameters used. This list takes the form of `[[df,params],[df,params], ... [df,params],[df,params]]`. After it has been generated, I would like to save this data to be processed in another script, but I am having trouble. Currently I am converting this list to a dataframe and using the `to_csv()` method from pandas, but this is mangling my data when I open it in another file - I expect the data types to be `[[dataframe,list][dataframe,list]...[dataframe,list][dataframe,list]]`, but they instead become `[[str,str],[str,str]...,[str,str],[str,str]]`. I open the file using the `read_csv()` method from pandas, then I convert the resulting dataframe back into a list using the `df.values.to_list()` method.

To clarify, I save the list to a .csv like this, where `out` is the list:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(out)
out.to_csv('optimized_ticker.csv')
```

And I open the .csv and convert it back from a dataframe to a list like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('optimized_ticker.csv')
list = df.values.tolist()
```

I figured that the problem was my dataframes had commas in there somewhere, so I tried changing the delimiter on the .csv to a few different things, but the issue persisted. How can I fix this issue, so that my datatypes aren't ? It is not imperative that I use the .csv format, so if there's a filetype more suited to the job I can switch to using it. The only purpose of saving the data is so that I can process it with any number of other scripts without having to re-run the simulation each time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to save a pandas dataframe is not via CSV if its only purpose is to be read by another pandas script. Parquet offers a much more robust option, it saves the datatypes for each column, can be compressed and you won't have to worry about things like comma's in values. Just use the following:

```
out.to_parquet('optimized_ticker.parquet')
```

```
df = pd.read_parquet('optimized_ticker.parquet')
```

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments pickle is also a possibility, so the solution depends on your case. Google will be your best friend in figuring out whether to use `pickle` or `parquet` or `feather`.

Comment: `pickle` is an alternative, similar approach which is a built-in with python and intended for just such requirements; it's faster that parquet and does not need an external library installing; however parquet can provide significant compression if size is an issue.

Comment: So are you suggesting I keep the part where I convert the list to a dataframe and save that using parquet/pickle/feather?

Comment: That should work if the List is what you want to save and restore later.